# PHP Get Contents and Include Not Quite What I Need

Tags: php

I've got a function like:

```
function get_div(){

   $fileLocation = 'form.php';
   $returnString = '<div id="myDiv">' . get_php_file($fileLocation) . '</div>';

   echo $returnString;

}

function get_php_file($file){
   return file_get_contents($file);
}
```

the problem is I have PHP in that file that I want executed as if it were part of the script.  (Instead of outputting `<?php my_function() ?>` throughout my page)

If I use `include $file` instead of `file_get_contents()` I end up with the included file, but the rest of my `$returnString` is shot...

Thoughts?

Comment: Is this strictly php or is there javascript too?

Comment: @malonso just php at this point.

Comment: Ok, sorry.  I was just a little confused by some of the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want output buffering.

```
ob_start();
include($file);
$returnString = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little confused by what exactly you are looking to do, but couldn't you just include the php file and w/in that feel have some string ($contentsToReturn) that you keep appending to?  get_php_file would become:

```
function get_php_file($file){
  require_once($file)
  return $contentsToReturn;
}
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm looking to store my string rather than output it right away.  using require_once() outputs the file then and there.

Comment: Unless you have a bunch of echo/print statements in $file, it won't output anything.  If $file does simply have a bunch of echo/print statements, just search/replace those so that instead of echo"stuff to echo", you end up with $returnString.="stuff to echo";.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to interpret php code, you can use include or require. Include will warn if it cannot find the file, require will stop execution. Here's what PHP.net says about it:

> > When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end tags.

oops, sorry didn't see you response about needing to buffer the string. Then ob_start as suggested is the proper way, then ob_get_contents when you need it.